# Why is this preg_match() code returning true in PHP CLI and false in Apache

Tags: utf-8, preg-match, php

I'm trying to validate some Arabic text encoded in UTF-8 and running into unexpected results in PHP 5.3.8. Running the following snippet through CLI returns true and false through Apache.

```
var_dump(preg_match("/[[:alnum:]]/i", "عايش لهدف"));
```

I have mbstring.func_overload set to 7 and my internal encoding set to UTF-8. I also have AddDefaultCharset set to UTF-8 in my .htaccess file.

Does anybody have any ideas what's going on?

Edit: Actually was using 5.3.8 (not 5.3.10)

Comment: did you change any `php_value` in .htaccess?

Comment: No. This occurs without an htaccess present as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running with different PHP settings. You can verify this by comparing the output of phpinfo() in Apache:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

To phpinfo() from the command line:

```
$ php -i
```

Comment: Which settings should I be looking for. It appears all the mbstring settings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your CLI is set to a non-utf8 charset (suggestion: switch to UTF8!) so PHP got some non-utf8 encoded string.

To make it work with an UTF8 string, use the `u` (utf8) modifier::

```
var_dump(preg_match("/[[:alnum:]]/iu", "عايش لهدف"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for this? It appears as though everything is set to UTF-8 in my php.ini file.

Comment: It is not related to PHP. If you run the code on the command line it receives a string with whatever charset your terminal uses.